# What is the correct way to return images from django rest api?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Im creating a Vue single page aplication with DRF backend. I have images stored in filesystem and one of my models has a field containing the adress of the image. 
How can i pass the image to the frontend?

Comment: You'll want to post some code showing what you've tried. Otherwise it is difficult for us to help you!

Answer (score 0):

If the html can access the image, try this

`<body>
        {% for item in imgs %}
            <img src="{{ item.img_url.url }}"><br/>
        {% endfor %}
    </body>`